# React Material-UI: More than one color for typography

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a theme with two text colors: #211806 and #010F1B.

```
const theme = {
  palette: {
    ...
    text: {
      primary: '#211806',
      secondary: '#010F1B'
    },
    ...
  }
};
```

However, I need to modify each text color in accordance with the state of the text (header, body, disabled and so on). Looking at [the default theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/), the palette is supposed to be:

```
const theme = {
  palette: {
    ...
    text: {
      primary: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)",
      secondary: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)"
    },
    ...
  }
};
```

so that it does not expect that one has more than one symbol color for the typography.

But I want to use both of the symbol colors depending on the base color (background, button and etc). How do I implement this two-colored text schema?

Comment: well that wouldn't really be adhearing to the guidelines of material-ui. What you want to do isn't supported because its not what you're supposed to do in mUI :)

Comment: So then would the best approach be creating my own function that takes (0,0,0,1) and returns ({someRGB},{someOpacity}) according to the state and the base background color?

Comment: You could control the colors yea :)

Comment: I see. But if what you said "its not what you're supposed to do in mUI" is true, why does this color tool (https://material.io/tools/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0) has both "Text on P" and "Text on S", which implies we can have two series of colors?